# Supervisor not restarting Horizon Queues

Tags: php, laravel, queue

So I might be misunderstanding something here and I'm not 100% sure if it's a Horizon problem, or a Supervisor problem, but was looking to see if anyone had experienced this before.

Essentially (and I don't think this is just limited to Horizon processes) it appears that Supervisor just doesn't attempt to restart any processes (at least, not all of the time).

I've currently got it running on 8 different servers (some our own dedicated hosting, others Digital Ocean droplets, and an AWS EC2 instance).

There are a variety of Laravel, PHP and Supervisor versions (from Laravel 5.7 and Supervisor 4.0.4 to Laravel 7.2.1 and Supervisor 3.4.0 - which seems to be latest version available in the CentOS repository and might need updating anyway)

This is an example config file that I'm using, which is essentially the same as the one provided in the Laravel docs.

```
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/<domain>/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=centos
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/<domain>/log/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

I don't believe the issue to be memory related as usage is usually pretty low at the time and I'm not seeing errors in that regard.

The log file is usually just the same thing over and over again:

> Horizon started successfully.

Which I assume is from whenever it has actually managed to restart, or when I've done it manually.

I've read another question on here that suggested that the user had the wrong command in the config, but I've verified this and used full paths to make sure it's correct.

Hopefully, someone here has more experience with this than I do?